# NavigationSplitView doesn't work using enum with associated type

Tags: swiftui, navigationsplitview

I have the following model in place for navigating to various pages:

```swift
enum Destination: Hashable {
  case today
  case activity
  case settings(path: SettingsPath? = nil)
  case project(project: ProjectItem? = nil)
  
  enum SettingsPath: Hashable {
    case cycles
    case donations

  }
}
```

In an ObservableObject, I'm using

`@Published var sidebarDestination: Destination? = .today`

And then in various `NavigationLink` buttons, I'm using the following initializer -
`NavigationLink(value: NavigationModel.Destination.activity...`

In the detail section of my NavigationSplitView I'm using a switch like so

```swift
detail: {
      if let destination = navigationModel.sidebarDestination {

        switch destination {

        case .today:
            TodayView()

        case .project(let project):
          // FIXME: Why is the detail view not updating
            if let selectedProject = project {
              IOSProjectDetailView(project: selectedProject)
            } else {
              EmptyView()
            }
...
```

I've noticed that the pages with an enum case with an associated value are not updating correctly - the title on the page will update, but none of the other content. The pages with an enum case without an associated type seem to work just fine.

All of this is using an iPad - the larger screen sizes

I have tried with iOS 16.0.1 as well as iOS 16.1 and it is not working there either.

Answer (score 1):

I would need to see your code in greater detail.

The 'selected' variable apparently is @Published var sidebarDestination: Destination? = .today.

That needs to be specified as such in the List definition (e.g. List(selection: $navigationModel.sidebarDestination) ).  It is also very important that the types match = they appear to here.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).